# How to handle pressing return key on textfield with multiple views

Tags: swift, delegates, uitextfield

**Case**

I have 3 views in one single view controller.

View 1 is always presented, it will function like a menu with different UIButtons.

View 2 is the login view, it will function as a login screen. This contains 2 UIButtons. UIButton 1 is login (it will execute the function tryLogin() see code below), UIButton 2 is register (change view). This view also contains 2 textfields. textfield 1 is e-mail, textfield 2 is password. View 2 is half the size of view 1, I give the users an idea that they need to login to "unlock" view 1.

View 3 is the register view, it will function for registering a new user. This contains also 2 UIButtons, and 2 textfields. The 2 UIButtons are: register (will execute tryMakeAccount()) and login. The 2 textfields are again, email and password.

**What I want**

When the user presses the return key when entering the email it needs to go to the password field. When the user presses the return key when entered the password, it needs to execute a function depending on what view is presented (login or register). I already did this when I only had 2 views (view 1 and view 2). However with the new view (view 3) my code doesn't work anymore. How to fix this?

**Code**

```
func setTextFieldDelegates() {
    loginEmail.delegate = self
    loginPassword.delegate = self
    registerEmail.delegate = self
    registerPassword.delegate = self
    loginEmail.tag = 0 //This worked well with 2 views
    loginPassword.tag = 1 //This worked well with 2 views
    registerEmail.tag = 0 //What to enter here?
    registerPassword.tag = 0 //What to enter here?
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Try to find next responder
    if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
        nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        tryLogin() //This should execute when user clicked return key on view 2 (login)
        tryMakeAccount() //this should execute when user clicked return key on view 3 (register)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Set unique tag numbers to every view and check the sender's tag in the handler method. You should have enough info to set the focus to the right view

Comment: I have no idea how to set the focus on the right view...

Comment: You know it... you already called becomeFirstResponder(). Make sure the TextView is visible in the parent view. If you check the sender's view tag (that you put earlier) you should know which view is releasing the keyboard input. From that you should know twich one is the next view. But if the view is not visible, it will lose the use of the keyboard (becomeFirstResponder() will have no effect)